# Парсинг Avito Requests

Tags: python, парсер, requests

У меня проблема. Я взялся выполнять заказ и покупатель требует информацию с профиля продавца в который возможно зайти только через авторизацию. Возможно ли как-то авторизоваться на avito через requests без блокировки?

Comment: Не знаю насчёт requests, но selenium не забанит

Answer (score 1):

1. У авито есть API - https://www.avito.ru/professionals/api
2. Selenium

Лучше использовать API